# DotPlot for prime numbers

Tags: plotting, prime-numbers

I was thinking to use a dotplot to give a description of prime numbers. On Wolfram [`website`](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DotPlot.html) there is written that each dotplot can be built by

```
    DotPlot[data_] := Module[{m = Tally[Sort[data]]},
    ListPlot[Flatten[Table[{#1, n}, {n, #2}] & @@@ m, 1], 
    Ticks -> {Automatic, Range[0, Max[m[[All, 2]]]]}]
    ]
```

I would like to have set of prime numbers on one axis and the natural numbers on the other one. Any idea? In addition, is it possible to realize a coprimality test by Dotplot (see figures below)? [image]
[image]

In addition,

I often investigate on Ramanujan primes. Is it possible to apply this procedure to them? I think so but which is the condition I should use? I am trying from several days with no results. According to wolfram references, the basic code from them is the following:

```
         l = Table[PrimePi[x] - PrimePi[x/2], {x, 10^4}]; // Timing

         1 + Last[Position[l, #]][[1]] & /@ Range[0, 50]
```

These two simple lines provide the first 50 Ramanujan primes.

Comment: Why are you destroying questions you've posted?

Comment: Because they are wrong!

Comment: Questions are wrong?

Answer (score 4):

The code for `DotPlot` is a starting point that needs to be tailored (e.g., add or modify `ListPlot` options) for specific applications. It is not clear to me what you are asking for, so I have tailored `DotPlot` for displaying the prime factors of `50!`

```
DotPlot[data_] := Module[{m = Tally[Sort[data]]},
  ListPlot[Flatten[Table[{#1, n}, {n, #2}] & @@@ m, 1],
   FrameTicks -> {Prime /@ Range[15], Range[0, Max[m[[All, 2]]], 4]},
   Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}},
   FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {"Prime Factors", "Count"}),
   PlotRange -> All,
   PlotLabel -> Style["Prime Factors of 50!", 14, Bold]]]

data = Flatten[ConstantArray @@@ FactorInteger[50!]];

DotPlot[data]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** For co-primes use [`CoprimeQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CoprimeQ.html) and display table with [`TableForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TableForm.html) or [`ArrayPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayPlot.html)

```
TableForm[
 table = Table[Boole[CoprimeQ[m, n]], {m, 13}, {n, 13}],
 TableHeadings -> {Range[13], Range[13]}]
```

[image]

```
table == Table[Boole[GCD[m, n] == 1], {m, 13}, {n, 13}]

(* True *)

ArrayPlot[table, FrameTicks -> {Range[13], Range[13]}]
```

[image]

Or

```
ArrayPlot[table, Mesh -> True, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {Range[13], Range[13]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As I see the code for dotplot provides several tools to investigate in prime numbers. Do you think that it is possible to use the same approach to plot a coprimality test? I mean, we could use a dot if the numbers are coprime and nothing otherwise. I have attached to figures of what I would like to plot in my first post.

Comment: @Spook82 - Neither of your figures appear to have anything to do with a `DotPlot`. You might want to look at `TableForm` or `Grid` and `ArrayPlot`.

Comment: Is it possible to realize them with these commands? Using the same structure of the code for Dotplot?