# Plot Ramanujan Primes

Tags: plotting, prime-numbers

I often investigate on Ramanujan primes. Is it possible to apply this procedure described in [DotPlot for prime numbers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/188073/dotplot-for-prime-numbers/188078?noredirect=1#comment490585_188078) ? I think so but which is the condition I should use? I am trying from several days with no results. According to wolfram references, the basic code from them is the following:

```
   l = Table[PrimePi[x] - PrimePi[x/2], {x, 10^4}]; // Timing

   1 + Last[Position[l, #]][[1]] & /@ Range[0, 50]
```

These two simple lines provide the first 50 Ramanujan primes. In particular, the primes are drawn in black in a binary image as shown below.

[image]

Is it possible to do the same with the Ramanujan primes? I mean, drawing black only the Ramanujan primes!

Comment: I rolled back your latest edit that removed the contents of your question. Since somebody put in effort to answer your question, you should leave it intact so their answer makes sense.

Answer (score 5):

It is not clear how you want these Ramanujan primes displayed. The following uses [`NumberLinePlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumberLinePlot.html) (introduced in v10.0)

```
l = Table[PrimePi[x] - PrimePi[x/2], {x, 10^4}];

rp = 1 + Last[Position[l, #]][[1]] & /@ Range[0, 50];

NumberLinePlot[Tooltip /@ rp, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Using [`ArrayPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayPlot.html) with [`Manipulate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html)

```
Manipulate[
 ArrayPlot[
  Array[Boole[MemberQ[rp, #1] && MemberQ[rp, #2]] &, {rp[[n]], 
    rp[[n]]}],
  FrameTicks -> Range[0, rp[[n]], Max[2, Round[rp[[n]]/10, 5]]]],
 {{n, 6}, 1, 25, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

**EDIT 2:**

```
Manipulate[
 ArrayPlot[Reverse@Array[
    Boole[MemberQ[rp, #1] && MemberQ[rp, #2]] &, {rp[[n]], rp[[n]]}], 
  FrameTicks -> {Table[{rp[[n]] - m + 1, m}, {m, rp[[1 ;; n]]}], 
    rp[[1 ;; n]]}],
 {{n, 6}, 3, 12, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: @Spook82 - I have guessed at what you may want; however, in the future specify exactly what you expect on each axis of a plot. Otherwise your questions may be closed as requiring additional information.

Comment: Dear Bob, thanks a lot and my sincerest apologies for my lack of details. In addition, I would like to know how I can invert the order of the axis-colomn. I mean that it should go from 0 to 45 and not from 45 to 0 as in the uploaded figure. I tried with the commands "rotate" and "reverse" but I did not work. The problem is that "Manipulate is not a graphic command" and I am not able to modify the "FrameTicks" in the code. I hope I was enough clear.